# ¿Remover arcos de un grafo dirigido genérico con lista de adyacencia?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una prueba de un grafo dirigido genérico con lista de adyacencia. Por ahora he podido agregar los vértices y los arcos del grafo. Sin embargo no se como eliminar arcos.

Tengo el siguiente código. Por ahora agrego los sucesores(arcos) y vértices.

**Arco.java**

```
package co.implementacion;

import co.interfaces.IArco;

public class Arco <K,V> implements IArco <K,V>{

private double costo;
private Vertice<K,V> origen, destino;


public Arco (Vertice<K,V> origen, Vertice<K,V> destino, double costo) {
    this.origen = origen;
    this.destino = destino;
    this.costo = costo;
}

@Override
public double darCosto() {
    return costo;
}

@Override
public Vertice<K,V> darOrigen() {
    return origen;
}

@Override
public Vertice<K,V> darDestino() {
    return destino;
}
}
```

**Vertice.java**

```
package co.implementacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import co.interfaces.IArco;
import co.interfaces.IVertice;

public class Vertice <K,V> implements IVertice{

private K id;
private V valor;
private boolean marca;

private List<Arco<K,V>> sucesores;


public Vertice (K id, V valor) {
    this.id = id;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.marca = false;
    sucesores = new ArrayList<Arco<K,V>>();
}

@Override
public Object darId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public Object darValor() {
    return valor;
}

@Override
public boolean darMarca() {
    return marca;
}

@Override
public List<Arco<K, V>> darSucesores() {
    return sucesores;
}

@Override
public void marcar() {
    marca = true;
}

@Override
public void desmarcar() {
    marca = false;
}

@Override
public Arco<K,V> darSucesor(Object idDestino) {
    return null;

}

@Override
public void darRecorridoEnProfundidad(List vertices) {

}

@Override
public void darRecorridoPorAnchura(List vertices) {

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean agregarSucesor(IArco sucesor) {

    try {
        sucesores.add((Arco<K, V>) sucesor);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public Arco<K,V> removerSucesor(Object idSucesor) {
    return null;
}
}
```

**GrafoDirigido.java**

```
package co.implementacion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import co.interfaces.IArco;
import co.interfaces.IGrafoDirigido;
import co.interfaces.IVertice;

public class GrafoDirigido<K, V> implements IGrafoDirigido {

private List<Vertice<K, V>> listaDeVertices;

public GrafoDirigido() {
    listaDeVertices = new ArrayList<Vertice<K, V>>();


}

@Override
public int darOrden() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Vertice<K, V> darVertice(Object idVertice) {

    Vertice<K, V> vertice = listaDeVertices.stream().filter(f -> f.darId().equals(idVertice)).findFirst().orElse(null);

    return vertice;
}

@Override
public Arco<K, V> darArco(Object idOrigen, Object idDestino) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean agregarVertice(Object idVertice, Object infoVertice) {

    try {
        Vertice<K, V> vertice = new Vertice(idVertice, infoVertice);

        listaDeVertices.add(vertice);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public Vertice<K, V> eliminarVertice(Object idVertice) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean agregarArco(Object idOrigen, Object idDestino, double 
costoArco) {

    try {
        Vertice<K, V> origen = darVertice(idOrigen);
        Vertice<K, V> destino = darVertice(idDestino);

        Arco<K, V> arco = new Arco(origen, destino, costoArco);

        origen.agregarSucesor(arco);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public Arco<K, V> eliminarArco(Object idOrigen, Object idDestino) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List darRecorridoEnProfundidad(Object idOrigen) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List darRecorridoPorAnchura(Object idOrigen) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

No se como eliminar el sucesor (arco).

La idea es llamar el método **eliminarArco(Object idOrigen, Object idDestino)** en **GrafoDirigido.java** que a su vez llama a **removerSucesor(Object idSucesor)** de **Vertice.java** para eliminar el sucesor de la lista de sucesores.

A parte también con el método **darSucesor(K idDestino)** de **Vertice.java** que es un método que retorna un arco sucesor, se le indican el vértice destino.

No se si el diseño esta mal pero lo que hice fue crear vértices que tienen múltiples sucesores(arcos) donde los arcos tiene un vértice de origen, destino y el costo.

Quiero saber si me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En GrafoDirigido la implementación sería simple, tal como mencionas, usando la API que ya tienes desarrollada:

```
@Override
public Arco<K, V> eliminarArco(Object idOrigen, Object idDestino) {
    return darVertice(idOrigen).removerSucesor(idDestino);
}
```

Luego en Vertice, la implementación requeriría remover realmente el arco. Una implementación usando iterator, sería algo así:

```
@Override
public Arco<K,V> removerSucesor(Object idSucesor) {
    Arco<K, V> arco;
    for(Iterator<Arco<K,V>> it = sucesores.iterator(); it.hasNext();;){
        arco = it.next();
        if(arco.darDestino().getId().equals(idSucesor)){
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
    return arco;
}
```

Nota: podría tener errores de compilación, pero es la idea.

Comment: Las funcionalidad del grafo ya esta completa sin embargo no se la manera de aplicar los algoritmo de bfs y dfs. Me puedes explicar como aplicar estos algoritmos a la estructura que estoy manejando, es decir en los métodos de recorrido.

Comment: Podrías abrir una nueva pregunta para recibir ayuda con tu implementación de busquedas BF y DF, pero la idea es que primero intentes hacerlo y luego preguntes dudas específicas